# MVC and EditorFor width

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, editorfor

Can I set the width of an EditorFor control on my View?

I have set a few parameters:

```
[Required, DisplayName("Payee Name"), StringLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

However, I can't seem to set the width of the textbox that gets rendered.

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)%>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Can this be done somehow?

I tried:

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new {width=50)%>
```

But no joy...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Instead of EditorFor, use TextBoxFor:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {style = "width:50px"})%>
```

Comment: That's not a full proof solution. What if we want the control to be a calendar control? TextBoxFor will not render dynamic Field.

Answer (score 18):

What's wrong with using CSS to style your control width?

Comment: That sounds good - but, how? I'd like to have it as a CSS, to have a generic setting for my controls.

Comment: @cdotlister - Try this: `<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "myCss" })%>` then in your .css file have `input.myCss {width: 50em;}`

Comment: I did that, but the control renders like this: <input class="text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="Bald Hills Medical Practice" />

Comment: @cdotlister - Oh, sorry, didn't pay close enough attention.  EditorFor uses a template to create the class, so you don't have control over the attributes unless you create your own Editor template.  Use TextBoxFor and LabelFor to do it yourself, and that will accept the new parameter.  Otherwise, you will have to create a custom editor template.

Answer (score 10):

In mvc 5 there is setting in site.css that sets the max-width=200 for all textareas. That confused me until i found this blogpost.  http://weblogs.asp.net/paullitwin/visual-studio-2013-asp-net-mvc-5-scaffolded-controls-and-bootstrap
as Paul Litwin puts it:

> Yes, Microsoft is for some reason setting the maximum width of all
>   input, select, and textarea controls to 280 pixels. Not sure the
>   motivation behind this, but until you change this or overrride this by
>   assigning the form controls to some other CSS class, your controls
>   will never be able to be wider than 280px.

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

So you if you are a pragmatic you change the max-width to eg 600px

Comment: I searched "280 pixel limit on text boxes" and similar things for MVC and couldn't find much until I found this buried comment.  This was incredibly frustrating just to find it here :(  Thanks for the right direction, upping this max limit has allowed me to actually design my site :)

Comment: I wouldn't imagine that textarea class could reflect an input element, but yeah. That did it!

Comment: @st_stefanov The styling applies to tags `input`, `select`, _and_ `textarea`. Per CSS rules.

Answer (score 9):

Replace `<%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new {width=50)%>` for this

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name,new { htmlAttributes = new { style = "width: 50px" }, }
```

Answer (score 7):

With BootStrap 3

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PriceIndicatorDesc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:280px" } })
```

Answer (score 3):

As previously mentioned, the place you want to go is in site.css

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

You can set any default value you want there or remove the block to get the Bootstrap default of 100%.  Personally, I added the following options so I could easily make some changes based on the control and field in question:

```
.form-control-25 {
    max-width: 25%;
}

.form-control-50 {
    max-width: 50%;
}

.form-control-75 {
    max-width: 75%;
}

.form-control-100 {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add "!important" to the css attribute to ensure that it overrides the default for TextBoxFor e.g. width:50px !important;

Answer (score 1):

Patrik Lindström is correct with the Max-width.

I was able to get around this by setting the max-width and width

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Source, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Source",  @style = "width: 900px;max-width: 900px;" } })
```

Comment: >>> YES <<<. 
This is the right answer for the question asked.
This works for me:

@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.BusinessAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @style = "width: 1000px;max-width: 1000px;" } })

Answer (score 0):

If you need a custom width outside of a normal CSS rule and you are using Editor Templates you can do

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { Width = 50})%>
```

Then in your editor template for String add this to your template

```
@Html.TextBox(s => {
...
    if (ViewBag.Width != null )
    {
       s.Width = ViewBag.Width;
    }
 }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file for Site.css, the default max-width is 280px if you had VS auto generate everything for you when you first created the MVC Project.  No matter how large of a width you set your `@html.editorfor` with a given id, it is limited by the below syntax.

```
input,
select,
textarea{
     max-width:280px
}
```

You can change it here by giving it a new max-width or max-height.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Core:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { style = "width: 50px" } })%>
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC5

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReplaceGroup, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "width:450px"  } })
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't very useful. When answering a question, it's good to add a description of why your answer is applicable, so the original poster and other readers can learn why you chose your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Above answer Yes and No. We need to use develop tool to check what styles used and modify them, they may have max-width, width; Then create own !important css to apply it, my case:

```
<style>
    textarea,
    input[type='text'],
    .form-group,
    .form-group-lg,
    .form-horizontal,
    .form-control,     
    .text-box,
    .single-line,
    .multi-line{
        width: 800px !important;
        max-width: 1000px !important;
    }
    .multi-line{
        height: 300px !important;
    }
    .form-horizontal{
        position:absolute;
        padding-left:15%;
    }
</style>
```

see attached image result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GVP1.png)